# "Login failed for user" trying to connect to SQL Server 2012

Tags: delphi, sql-server-2012-express, devart

I'm trying to get acces to a remote SQL Server, using SDAC.

(in fact I have to get access to the remote DB from android application)

What I've done to set up is [here](http://support.webecs.com/kb/a868/how-do-i-configure-sql-server-express-to-allow-remote-tcp-ip-connections-on-port-1433.aspx)

The configuration string of the TMSConnection is:

```
Password=mysaPwd;Data Source=RemoteIp;Initial Catalog=myDB;User ID=sa
```

What I get is : Login failed for user 'sa'

I tried to change the remote IP with local ip, starting the application locally on the server, but the error I get is the same.

I know that it's not a good way for safe reasons, but I want understand where the problem is

this is the authentication mode:

[image: Auth mode]

then, the connection configuration

[image: connection configuration]

Comment: It simply means you're providing an incorrect password, or the sa account is disabled or locked. Is the SQL Server configured to allow "Mixed Mode" for authentication?

Comment: @JerryDodge If I use PCNAME\SQLEXPRESS instead of the IP, the connection works.
I also tried to set up other users but the result is the same.
I have to connect remotely without a VPN so I have to use a pubblic IP

Comment: You should add this information to your question.

Comment: Please do not connect directly from android to SQL, but use a REST layer between you app and the DB, do not put your DB on the internet (bad, bad, no, REALLY bad idea!!!)

Comment: It could also mean that you're actually connecting to a different SQL Server instance in that case. Port 1433 is used for a default instance (without an instance name like `SQLEXPRESS`). Using instance names also requires you open the SQL Browser (port 1434). And yes, opening SQL Server to the web is a horrible plan. That's asking to get hacked.

Comment: I agree with you that is not a good idea connecting the app directly to SQLServer, but I'm not asking that! ;)

Comment: @JerryDodge the port 1434 is opened but the error persists.
Could be a problem related to the user permission?

Comment: Not sure, but opening port 1434 makes you even *more* vulnerable. That's practically telling the world "Hey look, I have a SQL Server, and here's how to connect to it!" If you must go this route, 1) disable SQL Browser (or just don't open it), 2) Choose a **non standard** port other than 1433 (and update it using the same instructions you used), and 3) connect using an address like `192.168.1.123, 12345` with `12345` being your new port number for example. Attackers love to find port 1433.

Comment: Let's just say there's a reason these capabilities are disabled by default when you install SQL Server.

Comment: Yes @JerryDodge I'll change the port for sure, but first I have to see the connection works, and after taht I'll do the changes you suggested.

Comment: Did you try using the port number as I suggested? At least try `MyComputer, 1433`. I have a feeling you're getting connected to a different server instance than you intend. You can install different instances on the same machine.

Comment: @JerryDodge, post your suggestion as an answer if you want!
You were right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jerry Dodge was right!
I tried to connect to a different server instance than I intended
There was an old instance of SQL server already installed.
Unfortunately the error message was not clear as something like "User name or password is incorrect" but "Login failed for user", that lead me down the wrong path.
Thank you all!

Comment: In the future, you might get an answer faster if you Google the error message or read the docs.